# how to add a hidden block and a toggle button to fancybox title?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I would like to have under each fancybox image, a button that shows a hidden block when clicked.

I made a simple toggle example but it does not work inside fancybox :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("p").toggle(1000);
    });

    $(".fancybox")
        .attr('rel', 'gallery')
        .fancybox({
        beforeLoad: function () {
            this.title = $(this.element).attr('caption');
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/azuron/koy9x64v/19/

Comment: Your code shows no attempt to create what you explain and what you want to do is unclear.

Comment: that's what I'm trying to create
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/koy9x64v/20/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**, you may rather set the text only (without HTML tags) that you want to toggle inside a (HTML5) `data` attribute like :

```
<a href="image01.jpg" data-caption="text to hide and seek" class="fancybox">open image</a>
```

**Second**, build the fancybox's `title` from within the `beforeLoad` callback and add the *toggler* button like :

```
beforeLoad: function () {
    var _caption =
        "<button class='toggler'>toggle</button>" +
        "<div style='display:none' class='caption'>" +
        $(this.element).data("caption") + "</div>";
    this.title = _caption;
}
```

**Notice** that you will be creating the HTML structure you need inside the `_caption` *variable* instead of writing it inside the `data` attribute. Also notice we are adding *classes* to the created elements so we can manipulate them later on.

**Third**, bind a `click` event that triggers the `.toggle()` method inside the `afterShow` callback like :

```
afterShow: function () {
    $(".fancybox-title").on("click", ".toggler", function () {
        $(".caption").toggle(400);
    });
}
```

**Notice** we are using the `.on()` method in its delegated form.

And **last** but not least, it would be better to set the fancybox *title* `type` as `inside` for a cleaner layout so add the helpers API option like :

```
helpers: {
    title: {
        type: "inside"
    }
}
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gheuqj7c/)**

Comment: Thank you so much this is what you need! Everything works fine!